# ODE system using Stokes parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-system

I am studying an exercise paper and I am encountering the following problem. With $u_i(t)=u_i$ ($i=1,2$) we have the system:

\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}
i \dot{u_1}  & = -(\omega_0 + i \beta) u_1 + \chi |u_1|^2 u_1 + \gamma u_2  \\
i \dot{u_2}  & = -(\omega_0 - i \beta) u_2 + \chi |u_2|^2 u_2 + \gamma u_1.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

He wants to identify the two conserved quantities and also write the system in a form of $S_i$'s. The Stokes parameters are the following:

\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}
& S_0 = |u_1|^2 + |u_2|^2,\quad
S_3 = |u_1|^2 - |u_2|^2,\\
& S_1 =  u_1 u_2^* + u_1^* u_2,\quad
S_2 = i(u_1 u_2^* - u_1^* u_2).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So how do I proceed in solving  the system or finding the conserved quantities? Any ideas would be helpful, because I can't find much stuff about Stokes parameters online also.

*Hint: for $\beta=0$, power $N$ and energy $E$ are conserved:
\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}
N = |u_1|^2 + |u_2|^2 \\
E = N + \frac{\chi}{2} \left( |u_1|^4 + |u_2|^4 \right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance

**Bonus question: is there any particular way to derive the equations for the Stokes parameters?

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319996/2451